# Usage of Bazel to build polyglot projects

Tags: javascript, kotlin, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a Kotlin JVM project that runs some JavaScript in an native runtime. Currently, the different language sources are defined in separate repositories and the JS file is webpacked and packaged as a JAR to be specified as a dependency of the JVM project. This works fine, but I want to merge the two repositories as they are inherently coupled. Rather than maintain an abundance of different build tooling, I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn and use a polyglot build system, like Bazel.

The current structure:

[image: Project file structure]

Essentially, there are two main packages I'm trying to build. The web package builds correctly and I can view the webpacked output via command line. Including the web `BUILD` file for full picture:

```
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "compileCore",
    srcs = ["index.ts"],
    tsconfig = "tsconfig.json",
)

filegroup(
    name = "internalCore",
    srcs = ["compileCore"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

load("@npm//webpack-cli:index.bzl", webpack = "webpack_cli")

webpack(
    name = "bundle",
    outs = ["bundle.prod.js"],
    args = [
        "--mode production",
        "$(execpath internalCore)",
        "--config",
        "$(execpath webpack.config.js)",
        "-o",
        "$@",
    ],
    data = [
        "internalCore",
        "webpack.config.js",
        "@npm//:node_modules",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The other important package is the nested `//jvm/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/plugin` package. This is essentially the final deliverable, which should be a JAR with the output of the web package included as resources.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "plugin",
    srcs = glob(["*.kt"]),
    deps = [
        # ... some deps
    ],
    resources = ["//web:bundle"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

This is seemingly straightforward, but errors during the build with:

```sh
❯ bazel build //jvm/src/...
INFO: Analyzed target //jvm/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/plugin:plugin (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /Users/jzucker/dev/GitHub/plugin-example-bazel/jvm/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/plugin/BUILD:12:15: error executing shell command: '/bin/bash -c external/bazel_tools/tools/zip/zipper/zipper c bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/jvm/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/plugin/plugin-resources.jar @bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/jvm/src/ma...' failed (Exit 255) bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
File web/bundle.prod.js does not seem to exist.Target //jvm/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/plugin:plugin failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.402s, Critical Path: 0.05s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

After some experimentation, this seems to be an issue of trying to bundle generated outputs as resources for a `kt_jvm_library`. If the resources reference a tangible source file from another package, then it works just fine. The main question here is whether this is the right pattern for Bazel or if I'm trying to abuse this technology. This seems like a relatively simple use case, but there is a line in the docs that concerns me the most:

> An invariant of all rules is that the files generated by a rule always belong to the same package as the rule itself; it is not possible to generate files into another package. It is not uncommon for a rule's inputs to come from another package, though.

From https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out this is actually a bug in the Bazel Kotlin ruleset:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/issues/281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the Bazel Kotlin ruleset:
github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/issues/281

Until that is fixed, you can package the resources in a `java_library` and include that as `resource_jars`.

```
java_library(
    name = "resources",
    resources = ["//web:bundle"],
    resource_strip_prefix = "web",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "plugin",
    srcs = glob(["*.kt"]),
    deps = [
        # ... some deps
    ],
    resource_jars = ["resources"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```